# Global NetCDF datasets with station time series data?

Tags: netcdf, climate, global, time-series

I´m working on a web application which uses temperatur and precipitation data. Currently i´m using only globally interpolated, multidimensional rasterdata from terrestrial stations (queried with x,y,t), but i also want to use global datasets with values of the original time series (which means vector- instead of raster data). So far i didn´t found many of these, although the NetCDF data model seems to be well suited for this case of data storage.

I want to use NetCDF because i need a standardized way of querying the data. That means i don´t want to use datasets which i hvae to convert or edit before i can use them. That´s why i would prefer NetCDF over simple ASCII or csv files...

Does any one know of possible Websites/Portals/Sources where i maybe could find the data i need in this or similar formats following the common data model (e.g. HDF5)?